# Record sound from web cast

Tags: sound

I want to record a radio webcast which does not offer MP3. The easiest way to do it seems to be recording all system sounds, playing the webcast and saving as MP3.

This is legal, by the way - I want to record a radio show in which my friend was interviewed. This is permitted by the radio station (and fair use according to Israeli law AFAIK).

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record any audio you can play using OutRec: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/quickly-record-soundcard-output-in.html

Comment: Thanks.  I got an error with that URL, but this one works: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/quickly-record-soundcard-output-in-ubuntu-with-outrec/

Answer (score 1):

You can use mplayer for this:

```
mplayer -dumpaudio -dumpfile radio url://of.your/radio
```

or

mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile radio url://of.your/radio

You can choose the filename `radio` on your own. After the stream has been saved, you can edit the file and convert it to a format which fits you.